# Convert list of list of objects into list of objects

Tags: automation, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws, infrastructure-as-code

`I have a local variable that looks like the below in the outputs

```
  + karpenter_node_instance_types              = [
      + [
          + "t3.small",
          + "t3.medium",
          + "t3.xlarge",
        ],
      + [
          + "g5.xlarge",
          + "p2.xlarge",
        ],
    ]
```

I am trying to break in this into a simple list of object so that I can use each one of them in my data block.

I want something like :

```
  + karpenter_instance_list                    = [
      + {
          + name = "g5.xlarge"
        },
      + {
          + name = "p2.xlarge"
        },
      + {
          + name = "t3.xlarge"
        },

      + {
          + name = "t3.medium"
        },
      + {
          + name = "t3.small"
        },
    ]
```

I can then simply loop thru this and use it in the data block as:

```
data "aws_ec2_instance_type" "find_karpenter_instance_type" {
  for_each      = { for index, instance in local.karpenter_instance_list : index => instance if(length(instance.name) > 0)}
  instance_type = each.value.name
}
```

Any ideas on how I can generate karpenter_instance_list ?? As of now I can only get either the values from index --> 0 or index 1, there could be values more than what I have in the list.

I am doing this as of now to get values from index 0 and 1

```
  karpenter_instance_list_one = flatten(toset([
    for index, instance_type in local.karpenter_node_instance_types : {
      name = element(instance_type, index)    

  ]))

  karpenter_instance_list_two = flatten(toset([
    for index, instance_type in local.karpenter_node_instance_types : {
      name = element(instance_type, index + 1)
    }
  ]))

  karpenter_instance_list = distinct(setunion(local.karpenter_instance_list_one, local.karpenter_instance_list_two))
```

Comment: You are already aware of the `flatten()` operation, what's wrong with just applying that directly to `karpenter_node_instance_types`? The result will just be a plain list of instance types, rather than a list of mappings from the key "name" to the instance type, but either that structure isn't really necessary or it's easy to create it using a "for" expression (which you are also already aware of).

Comment: I thought that I would flatten the result itself and that's why I had flatted before the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the `flatten` function to convert the list of lists into a list, then iterating it with a for returning a list of objects, as follows:

```
locals {
  karpenter_node_instance_types = [
    [
      "t3.small",
      "t3.medium",
      "t3.xlarge",
    ],
    [
      "g5.xlarge",
      "p2.xlarge",
    ],
  ]

  karpenter_instance_list = [
    for instance_type in flatten(local.karpenter_node_instance_types) : {
      name = instance_type
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The above suggestion worked for me,        + karpenter_instance_list                    = [
          + {
              + name = "t3.small"
            },
          + {
              + name = "t3.medium"
            },
          + {
              + name = "t3.xlarge"
            },
          + {
              + name = "g5.xlarge"
            },
          + {
              + name = "p2.xlarge"
            },
        ]